# Python трансляция видео потока

Tags: python

Можно ли устроить трансляцию веб камеры без выделенного ip ?

Comment: Зависит от того, какую именно трансляцию с технической точки зрения вы хотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Но потребуется дополнительных усилий.

1. Например воспользоваться сторонним сервисом, который решает проблему отсутствия "белого" IP, но скорее всего такой сервис будет платным.
2. Либо можете арендовать VPS (он не дорогой, и у VPS будет статический 'белый' IP), там поднять VPN сервер и через VPN туннель соединить камеру с сервером.
3. Есть еще более экзотический вариант, посмотреть в сторону IPv6.